# How show hide image in paperclip when no image present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, paperclip

How can I prevent the image tag that calls the associated image from displaying if no image is associated with the record?

```
<%= image_tag @agent.avatar.url %>
```

...gives me the text "Missing" if there is no image associated with that agent.  I want to test to see there is an image available first, then render the above tag if the test returns true.

Better yet, is there anyway for me to specify a default image if no image is specifically provided?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I use the following to find wether a model has an associated attachment:

```
<% if @agent.avatar.file? %>
  <%= image_tag @agent.avatar.url(:normal) %>
<% else %>
  No attachment available!
<% end %>
```

Comment: sweet, used paperclip for a long time and didn't know about this ;)

Comment: Although the other answer is a better general-purpose solution, I'm using this one because I want to rearrange the layout if something doesn't have an attached image, not just display a placeholder image.

Comment: Very nice!  This is an easy quick fix.

Answer (score 53):

If avatar has multiple sizes:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, 
                  :styles => {:small => '30x30#', :large => '100x100#'}, 
                  :default_url => '/images/missing_:style.png'
```

for Rails 3:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, 
                  :styles => {:small => '30x30#', :large => '100x100#'}, 
                  :default_url => '/assets/images/missing_:style.png'
```

Comment: i did a variation with default_url being '/images/:style/missing_modelname.png' for multiple models that have attachments

Answer (score 31):

Okay, so I got one part of it.

Specifying a default image happens in the model

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :default_url => '/images/brokers/agents/anonymous_icon.jpg'
```

Answer (score 18):

Few bytes less:

```
<% if @agent.avatar? %>
  <%= image_tag @agent.avatar.url(:normal) %>
<% else %>
  No attachment available!
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is better to use :default_url rather than conditions.

Answer (score 1):

If a default_url has been specified in the model you can use the method present? to check if the url is the default or an uploaded one.

```
<% if @agent.avatar.present? %>
  <%= image_tag @agent.avatar.url(:normal) %>
<% else %>
  No attachment available!
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
user.photo.exists?(:medium).
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem before, but solved it by using:

```
<% if @post.image.exists? %>
<%= image_tag @post.image.url %>
<% end %>
```